# Using Guided Template langauge with Ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder, mobileconnect, gtl

I am using GTL with Ampscript to personalise an SMS by creating the task activity in Journey Builder which then talks to Salesforce data and triggers a SMS. I have used the description field to insert the SMS message.

This is what I did as per the instructions [here](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/guide_template_language/how_to_use_guide_template_language_with_ampscript_and_server_side_javascript/)

```
{{=Uppercase(Event."SalesforceObj8e3ec1484b"."Contact:FirstName")}}, message here
```

And I receive this as an SMS

```
""=Uppercase(Event."SalesforceObj8e3ec1484b"."Contact:FirstName")"", message here
```

It is basically replacing the curly braces with quotes. Did somebody had this problem? Do we have a work around on this?

Answer (score 1):

In order to use GTL in SMS messages, you will need to escape OMM delimiters using the prefix `%%{={{ }}=}%%`.

For example, if you are using: `{{=Add(1,1)}}`

You should use: `%%{={{ }}=}%%{{=Add(1,1)}}` which will send an SMS with the output `2`.

Now onto your code. It appears that you are attempting to use Journey Builder's data binding in the Event context within an SMS message. I'd be **very surprised** if this works. I'm pretty sure that you will need to use an AMPscript Lookup function instead (to reference a Data Extension containing the contact's first name) as I don't believe data binding contexts are passed to MobileConnect. You will need to rely on the `MOBILE_NUMBER` personalisation string in MobileConnect to lookup a corresponding first name using the Lookup AMPscript function.

Comment: Hi @eliot-harper, did you manage to have data binding contexts in Mobile Push/ Mobile Connect ? Thanks!